# Batteries lose functionality

Tags: mobile-robot, battery, webots

In Webots: I want my little robot drive to a fully charged charger (green pointlight and cylinder) and drain its energy. While the battery loses energy it should change its color.

It works as long as I stay in the Webots Tour setup of the battery device. I can make changes of the bot and the arena. Everything works. But as soon as I introduce a second robot or just close Webots and open it again the light and shape stays green when my robot comes into contact. This happened every time over multiple different worlds. Every time I introduce the battery to a new robot Webots crashes and afterwards the charger is not working anymore. Or I close the program in the battery setup and after reopening it does not change the colors. So I don't know what my mistake is.

I use R2023a because I use Python. My Robot has 50/100/30 and the Charger nodes have 100/100/3. When I introduce a new robot or battery and change the second number it crashes. I even deinstalled and reinstalled Webots. All the same.

I safe in the red initial state and when I run than It changes to the green initial state. And not because it charged fully. Because the initial values in the nodes changes that when I reset the simulation the initial values are green again.

[My output](https://webots.cloud/AchS3z2?upload=webots)

The Charger loses its energy but does not change the color.

- [World file](https://github.com/MaximilianKlein92/Webots-Breitenberg/blob/main/WeBots%20Batterie%20and%20Vehicle%202)
- [Controller.py](https://github.com/MaximilianKlein92/Webots-Breitenberg/blob/main/Vehicle%202%20controller%20with%20wall%20avoidance)

Comment: To help solving your issue you should provide additional information.
Which version of Webots are you using?
Which values did you set to the `battery` field of your robot?
Could you provide a minimal sample simulation where you can reproduce the problem?
I tried to relocate the sample "battery.wbt" world, add a E-puck robot with battery field set, restart Webots and run the simulation but I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @HackMack: please edit your original question to provide more details instead of giving details in a comment.

Comment: @HackMack: please edit your original question to provide more details instead of giving details in a comment.

Comment: If you can reduce your world file to the minimum and the resulting WBT is not too long you can copy it in your question formatted as code.
Otherwise you should host your files somewhere else and link to them in the question (for example https://gist.github.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "gradual" appearance change of the [Charger](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/charger) node that is used in the default "battery.wbt" world and in your world uses the initial color value of the [Charger](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/charger) first child node to determine the color change when loosing energy.

Here is the documentation of the "gradual" field from the Charger node documentation:

> `gradual`: defines the behavior of the indicator. If set to TRUE, the indicator displays a progressive transition ***between its original color and the `emissiveColor` specified in the Charger node***, corresponding to the present level of charge.

In the default "battery.wbt" world file, the `emissiveColor` of the `Charger.Trasform.Shape.appearance` and the `color` of the `Charger.Trasform.PointLight` are set to red (`1 0 0`). This is the important settings that makes the Charger color change when charging a battery and loosing energy.

It seems that you modified and saved the default "battery.wbt" after running the simulation, so these initial settings were lost.

Here is the [Charger](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/charger) structure you should use:

```
Charger {
  translation -0.43 0.43 0
  rotation 0 0 1 -1.570795
  children [
    Transform {
      translation 0 0 0.15
      children [
        Shape {
          appearance PBRAppearance {
            baseColor 0 1 0
            transparency 0.7
            roughness 0.2189099510000001
            metalness 0
            emissiveColor 1 0 0   # this field should be set to a different color than Charger.emissiveColor
          }
          geometry DEF CHARGER_GEOM Cylinder {
            height 0.3
            radius 0.2
            subdivision 24
          }
        }
        PointLight {
          attenuation 0 0 12
          color 1 0 0  # this field should be set to a different color than Charger.emissiveColor
          intensity 0.53
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  name "charger0"
  battery [
    100, 100, 4
  ]
  radius 0.2
}
```

I could also reproduce the crash when adding battery values while running the simulation. I'm now inspecting and fixing it.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://www.cyberbotics.com/).*

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick responds! :) I tryed to change the colors but when I do, the second I press the run button it automatically changes back. So I safe in the red initial state and when I run than It changes to the green inital state. And not becouse it charged fully. because the inital values in the nodes changes thad when I reset the simuation the inital values are green again.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. The inital color defines the color when the batter is completely empty. But given that at the beginning of the simulation the robot battery is full the color is immediately changed to the `Charger.emissiveColor` that is green by default. I didn't test the reset in your world but running the simulation and restarting it with these settings works just fine.

Comment: Pay also attention that after editing and saving the world at time step 0, you have to reload and not reset the simulation.

Comment: The other way is actually possible. If the empty charger is initally green and the full should be red it works. But the other way around is not possible. It just stays green if empty or full. I can work further with this way around but conceptually it is weird.

Comment: Jeah Reloading the world, after changeing the values and saving them, fixed it!

Comment: Nice! Could you please accept the answer if it solved your issue?

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a greate weekend and Christmas :)